# Dynamically Scaffolded Views Apparently Not Generated

Tags: grails, scaffolding, grails-3.0

***IMPORTANT ---> ... it looks like this is a currently known bug in Grails 3.1.1 ([Issue #9729](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9729)) Apparently its been fixed in 3.1.2 ...***

--- My Original Post is Below ---

It appears as though no views are generated when executing a dynamically scaffolded controller. I'm using Grails 3.1.1 (w/ scaffolding plugin specified in dependencies), JDK 8, all running on OSX...

My test case is a very simple 'Book' example with the following domain class and controller...

```
// Domain Class...
package scaffoldtest

class Book {

    String name
    String author

    static constraints = {
    }
}


// Controller (scaffolded)...
package scaffoldtest

class BookController {

    static scaffold = Book

}
```

When I issue a run-app command and navigate to http://localhost:8080/book/index I get the following exception...

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI: /book/index
Class: javax.servlet.ServletException
Message: Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
```

...and FWIW, I also cannot see any sign of the generated view files down the "/build" tree... Also, and again FWIW, I believe I've read somewhere that dynamic scaffolding was temporarily removed during the initial versions of Grails 3, but my understanding (and the Grails manual concurs) is that dynamically generated views were put back in. In any case, I'm not seeing why the above dynamic scaffolding example doesn't work...

Comment: Have you tried `static scaffold = true` instead? Just wondering.

Comment: Using a value of 'true' was actually the previous way of specifying the dynamic scaffolding (prior to Grails 3.0 I believe). The new way is to explicitly use the target domain class as the value...

Comment: Interesting. I know both ways existed prior to 3.0 and for differing reasons. I thought perhaps using `true` might resolve your issue since the Domain and Controller match in name (convention). It was just a suggestion.

Comment: I just found this issue as a currently active bug report in the Grails issue tracker. I've added the link to my original post...

Answer (score 0):

FYI, that bug should be fixed in Grails 3.1.2, which was released earlier today. See the changelog at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues?q=milestone%3Agrails-3.1.2.